# Making div responsive with margin 0 auto in it

Tags: css

The code below shows 3 circles horizontally. I want the code to work for responsive website. Please guide me how can I do so. Thanks.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9jjqugd/).

```
<div id="responsivearea" style="width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; clear: none;">
    <img class="  wp-image-2520 alignleft" style="float: left; clear: none; margin-left: 120px;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/good-employer.png" alt="good employer" width="201" height="199" /> 
    <img class="  wp-image-2521 alignleft" style="float: left; clear: none;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/gift-of-health.png" alt="gift of health" width="201" height="199" />
    <img class="  wp-image-2522 alignleft" style="float: left; clear: none;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Change-maker.png" alt="Change maker" width="201" height="199" />
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap solution will be fine for you ?

Comment: don't give it a fixed width!

Comment: @Junaid: Yes. It would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depend and what you want but fixed width and high margin isn't the solution, you need another wrapper on your image for center them, and adjust your `CSS`:

```
<div id="responsivearea">
    <div class="img-center">
        <img class="wp-image-2520 alignleft" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/good-employer.png" alt="good employer" width="201" height="199" /> 
        <img class="wp-image-2521 alignleft" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/gift-of-health.png" alt="gift of health" width="201" height="199" /> 
        <img class="wp-image-2522 alignleft"  src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Change-maker.png" alt="Change maker" width="201" height="199" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css :

```
#responsivearea{
    max-width: 900px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.img-center{
    display:inline-block;
}
.alignleft{
    float: left; 
    clear: none;
}
```

here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/x9jjqugd/1/

Hope I help !

Answer (score 1):

Don't use floats, use `text-align:center` on the parent.

```css
div {
    max-width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    width: 201px;
    height:199px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/good-employer.png" alt=""/>
    <img src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/good-employer.png" alt=""/>
    <img src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/good-employer.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: How is it responsive ?

Comment: Define "responsive". what do you want it to do? The images stay centered.

Comment: Well you are right ... the question is badly asked !! I was thinking "responsive" is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design ...